# Help please with XEN PCI-device passthough

Tags: xen, pci

I have problem with PCI passthough in XEN.

kernel: 4.15.0-23-generic
CPU: Intel Core i7 - saw specifications on Intel website: it supports VT-d, VT-x and all other technologies!

Checking XEN is ready IOMMU / VT-d / VT-x:

```
xl dmesg | grep -i hvm
```

output:

```
(XEN) HVM: ASIDs enabled.
(XEN) HVM: VMX enabled
(XEN) HVM: Hardware Assisted Paging (HAP) detected
(XEN) HVM: HAP page sizes: 4kB, 2MB
```

check IOMMU:

```
(XEN) Enabling APIC mode:  Flat.  Using 1 I/O APICs
(XEN) I/O virtualisation enabled
```

So, I started (Passthough a PCI USB controller, where xx:yy.z is ID of lspci):

```
# modprobe xen-pciback
# xl pci-assignable-add xx:yy.z
```

Check device is ready to be passthough:

```
sudo xl pci-assignable-list
```

It shows me: 0000:xx:yy.z so I was happy that my device is ready. Then:

```
sudo nano /etc/xen/ubuntu.hvm
```

I edit config adding this line:

```
pci = ['0000:xx:yy.z']
```

Then start:

```
sudo xl create /etc/xen/ubuntu.hvm
```

And i see ERROR:

```
Parsing config from /etc/xen/ubuntu.hvm
libxl: error: libxl_pci.c:1111:do_pci_add: Domain 2:xc_assign_device failed: Cannot allocate memory
libxl: error: libxl_pci.c:1306:libxl__add_pcidevs: Domain 2:libxl_device_pci_add failed: -3
libxl: error: libxl_create.c:1458:domcreate_attach_devices: Domain 2:unable to add pci devices
libxl: error: libxl_domain.c:1003:libxl__destroy_domid: Domain 2:Non-existant domain
libxl: error: libxl_domain.c:962:domain_destroy_callback: Domain 2:Unable to destroy guest
libxl: error: libxl_domain.c:889:domain_destroy_cb: Domain 2:Destruction of domain failed
```

Any ideas? I googled, but not found my problem! My second AMD Ryzen PC succeded passthough PCI USB without any errors.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure that dom0 is not capturing the PCI device you are trying to pass-through at boot time.

Make sure this is specified in `/etc/default/grub.d/xen.cfg`

at the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_XEN="pciback.hide=(xx:yy.z)"`

run `update-grub`

and reboot.